# ios movable divs - prevent underlying div events

Tags: javascript, ios

What is not a problem:

Moving/Resizing a div. This behaves as expected on all platforms.

The problem, as it exists, *only* seems to affect apple ios, and is described as follows:.

If the moved div has been parked over another element (div, span, button) and that element contains an onclick event, that underlying onclick fires when the next move operation is complete.

I have tried stopPropagation and cancelBubble event handling, at the moveable div level, at doc level, at underlying element level. All to no avail.

I have aslo tried manipulating an underlying 'mobi div', adjusted for zIndex to block the underlying element (which works great for iframe issues but not for this).

I'm not using transform, just straight up javascript positioning.  I'm aware that tranform offers speed advantages (using the GPU) and does not create this issue, but for other browser compat reasons, I want to avoid transform.

Has anyone else experienced this on ios, or is there some quirky 'moz-quit-screwing-with-stuff' thing that apple has that I don't know about?

Please, no library based suggestions.  Just pure javascript (assuming a solution exists).

I can probably hack around the issue using a timer and a basic 'on_ios_move' type of construct, but it really doesn't seem elegant.

many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, please ignore this question.

This now seems to happen only on older ios (5.1 for example).

I'm pretty sure I tested this previously on ios 7 and saw the same effect, but I guess not, since 6.x and now 9.x seem okay.

As I'm sure anyone who has spent 15 hours a day re-working code can attest, one's testing rubrick can get a tad abstract at the end of a frustrating day.

Apologies for the erroneous question.

I'll probably post the code once I get the 'dev scruffy' removed, assuming anyone is looking for a cross browser move/resize solution without transform/translate and without the need for a library solution.

Happy Coding.